# Getting started with Econophysics

Tags: econophysics

This is my first post on stack exchange.

I am high school student having good grasp of high school physics concepts.
Recently I heard about econophyics- i.e. application of physics laws  to the economics. I want to understand more about this concept. So I am looking for simple examples that can explain how economists are using physics. Unfortunately the articles that I found are way advance and I am unable to understand.

I seek your help in this regard. Please explain using very simple examples and terms  such as those involving profit, loss, break even point,  demand supply. I also understand probability distributions, gaussian curve, random variables, central limit theorem etc.

Also point me to a reference which is written for general audience in simple language.

Thanks and regards

Comment: I think you should know that "econophysics" is not about economists using physics but physicists trying to do economics; econophysics is widely rejected by economists.

Answer (score 1):

Econophysics isn't simply the application of physical laws to economics. It is the application of a particular field of physics,  statistical mechanics, to economic problems.

Statistical mechanics is not a simple subject, it is a relatively recent development of physics$^1$, it is based on thermodynamics and calculus of probability.
The articles of econophysics can  be incomprehensible without a specific background of knwoledge of statistical mechanics.

You can try to read this book, Richmond, Mimkes, Hutzler,  *Econophysics and* *Physical Economics,*  which is written also by a physicist.  It explains you the basic necessary concepts of statistical mechanics, applied to economics. It should be a reliable book, as it is published by Oxford University Press.

https://www.amazon.it/Econophysics-Physical-Economics-Peter-Richmond/dp/0199674701/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1LUXCRJGS2GT&keywords=econofisica&qid=1670520612&sprefix=econofisica%2Caps%2C303&sr=8-5#customerReviews

---

$^1$  <sup>The recent italian Nobel Prize for physics Giorgio Parisi is one of the most important scientific authorities in mechanical statistics.</sup>